# Django + mod_wsgi + apache: ImportError at / No module named djproj.urls

Tags: python, django, importerror, django-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my Django application on my linode server with apache and mod_wsgi.

`file: /srv/www/example.com/djproj/django.wsgi`

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/example.com/djproj')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/example.com/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

`file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com`

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html

WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/example.com/djproj/django.wsgi

<Directory "/srv/www/example.com/djproj">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log 
CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
```

When I visit / of my site I get this **error**:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://example.com/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-    py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py    2.6.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  250.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  279.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  274.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named djproj.urls
```

I can't get it to work. Ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Either change all your module/package entries and imports to exclude the project name, or put `/srv/www/site.com` in `sys.path` as well.

Comment: This was my problem too. Why the hell isn't this mentioned in the docs though!!!!!!!!!! I thought you just had to specify the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and django would then take care of the rest.

Comment: Note that the path should actually read "/srv/www/site.com", **since that's what matches what the asker has put in their question**.

Answer (score 36):

I second Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841531/django-mod-wsgi-apache-importerror-at-no-module-named-djproj-urls/5841543#5841543). You must add the path to your *project directory* as well as the path to *its parent directory* to `sys.path`. Here is an example of the WSGI script file I use. I keep the file inside the project directory.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../")))

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "PROJECT_NAME.settings"

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: Getting a `Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [0] in u'[]'` when trying to insert (or append) `../../` & `../` to the path

Comment: Wow you are my hero, been fighting with this for like 3 hours now, didn't think to move stuff further up the path list.  I wish I could upvote more!

Comment: You saved my life ! Damn! i've pased two days searching for this solution. Thanks man!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I had been hitting a wall cuz of this for the last 4-5 hours!!

Answer (score 11):

Seconding ayaz' answer. It's important that the paths you're specifying be at the beginning of the search path, which means you need to use insert..

Here's mine. When I was doing an 'append' I was getting intermittent issues. This made it rock solid. Hope this helps.

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/srv/www/Appname')
sys.path.insert(1, '/srv/www')
```

Comment: This might have just saved my life and hours of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 5):

try following this tutorial - http://singlas.in/5-step-tutorial-for-using-django-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi/

Make sure to add both Django directory and Django Project Directory to system path. your wsgi.py should look like

```
import os,sys

#comments
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_project.settings")
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/django/directory/django_project')
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/django/directory')

#comments
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 2):

What corrected this error for me --

Changing settings.py from:

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

To this:

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

Comment: This was a thorn in my side also. This was the cause. I had to search (egrep) my entire site to find out where it was trying to get the urls file from.

Answer (score 1):

where you have `djproj.urls` maybe try just `urls`