# Flask, mod_wsgi, and Apache: ImportError

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm getting this in my error logs:

> ImportError: No module named flask

It looks exactly like in [Django + mod_wsgi + apache: ImportError at / No module named djproj.urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841531/django-mod-wsgi-apache-importerror-at-no-module-named-djproj-urls), but I tried that solution, and it doesn't seem to work... I am correctly inserting the app home and parent folder into the system path, but this error is still coming up.

Navigating to my page still brings up the 500 page.

More information: I'm using [Amazon EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) free tier, with Apache in the form of httpd. Everything is installed correctly, I'm pretty sure...

Here's my stuff (app name *badassery* and app home folder name *hatemail* - I change my mind a lot):

Error log

```
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148] mod_wsgi (pid=28143): Target WSGI script '/home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148] mod_wsgi (pid=28143): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.wsgi'.
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148]   File "/home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148]     from badassery import app as application
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148]   File "/home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.py", line 6, in <module>
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148]     from flask import Flask, request, session, url_for, redirect, render_template, abort, g, flash, _app_ctx_stack
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148] ImportError: No module named flask
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148] mod_wsgi (pid=28143): Target WSGI script '/home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148] mod_wsgi (pid=28143): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.wsgi'.
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148]   File "/home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148]     from badassery import app as application
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148]   File "/home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.py", line 6, in <module>
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148]     from flask import Flask, request, session, url_for, redirect, render_template, abort, g, flash, _app_ctx_stack
[Sun Nov 11 07:14:45 2012] [error] [client 18.189.71.148] ImportError: No module named flask
```

#### badassery.wsgi

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,'/home/ec2-user/hatemail')
sys.path.insert(1,'/home/ec2-user')

from badassery import app as application
```

Additions to the httpd.conf file

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 54.243.61.41
        DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user/hatemail"

        WSGIDaemonProcess badassery user=apache group=apache processes=1 threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/hatemail/badassery.wsgi
        WSGIScriptReloading On

        <Directory /home/ec2-user/hatemail>
                WSGIProcessGroup badassery
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Directory structure

```
~
    hatemail
        badassery.py
        badassery.wsgi
        Procfile
        README
        requirements.txt
        schema.sql
        static/
        templates/
        venv/bin/activate
```

Yes, I am doing "if **name** == 'main': app.run()".

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are the files readable by the Apache user?

Comment: can you run an interactive Python shell and type:

`import flask`

What do you see?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're deploying a virtualenv, you'll have to make sure to activate it first. You should update your wsgi file like this (updating the values to match your environment):

```
activate_this = '/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this)

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/flask/appname')
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/ec2-user/hatemail')
sys.path.insert(1,'/home/ec2-user')

from badassery import app as application
```

If you aren't deploying a virtualenv, you probably just need to make sure that Flask is installed on your system. If you've already installed `setuptools` you can just:

```
easy_install flask
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have any problems with importing when using `wsgi_mod`, make sure you try explicitly pointing to the import files that are causing problems:

```
sys.path.append('/home/foo/www/Forms')
```

then do your import!