# Django + mod_wsgi + apache: ImportError: No module named <module name>

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Setting up my first app. I started on the django development server, and am now moving things to an apache setup so that I can code in my target prod environment. I've gotten mod_wsgi set up successfully and got a successful "Hello World!". Now I'm having issues actually getting my app to respond in apache the way it did in the django dev server.

Here's my directory structure:

- /var/www/www.example.com/  [site directory]

  - Example  [my app]

    - wsgi.py
    - settings.py
  - users [another django module i wrote]
  - trips [yet another django module i wrote]

Now, in my virtual host file, I have the following line:
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/www.example.com/Example/wsgi.py

And in my wsgi.py file, I have the following lines:

```
sys.path.append('/var/www/www.example.com/Example')
sys.path.append('/var/www/www.example.com/trips')
sys.path.append('/var/www/www.example.com/users')
```

Yet, here's the error I'm getting:

```
[Sun Jan 06 21:37:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named trips
```

What do I need to do to get django and mod_wsgi to recognize my trips and users apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841531/django-mod-wsgi-apache-importerror-at-no-module-named-djproj-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't add every module to sys.path.
Instead you should add `/var/www/www.example.com` to sys.path.